# Create temporary database php

Tags: php, zend-framework

This might sounds stupid but is it possible to create temporary table/database using Zend Framework and Mysql? If it is possible, may I have a sample code? Thanks

Comment: http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/create-database.html read the manual and use the queries in php as you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
/* @var $db Zend_Db */
$db->execute('CREATE TABLE tmp LIKE table_something');
```

Comment: This will make a table, not a database. The question is asking about how to make an actual database.

Comment: ...create temporary *table*/database

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as you would create a normal talble, just add 'TEMPORARY' after 'CREATE'. Such tables will be dropped after the connection closes.

```
$db->execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp');
```

Answer (score 2):

In Mysql, you can create temporary table with engine `BLACKHOLE`

It creates tables on the fly, means it will only be available upto one HTTP request, and on completing it will be deleted.

`CREATE TABLE table_name engine = BLACKHOLE;`

I don't know how to do in Zend, but may be something like this would help:

`$db->execute("CREATE TABLE table_name engine = 'BLACKHOLE'");`

Comment: Blackhole engine does not save data, even for a single request. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-engines.html

Comment: It will hold the data temporarily during the query. It don't store it there permanently.